# how to check for a linked string inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

I have an array, let us say, `$breadcrumb = array("home" , "groups", "Create content", "some other element" "so on");` I want to check if it contains a string "Create content" and then unset the string, but my problem is that "Create content" is a link (anchored) and not just a plain string, I tried `in_array()`, but not successful.  How do I look for it, to make it more clear?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function phptemplate_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
    if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
        if(in_array("Create content",$breadcrumb)){
            foreach($breadcrumb as $key => $value){
                if("Create content" == strip_tags($value)){
                    unset($breadcrumb[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' › ', $breadcrumb) .'</div>';
}
```

Note: I know it can be done anyway if I ommit `in_array()` check but I don't want to loop through the array unecessarily, if the `'Create content'` is not in the array.

Edit: actual array is:

```
array(
[0]=>home
[1]=> groups
[2]=> my group
[3]=> Create content
 )
```

here `'Create content'` may occupy any position.
Note: all elements are links (anchored).

Comment: What does your actual array look like?

Comment: Please fix your indenting when posting questions. Nobody here wants to read that.

Comment: What does it mean - they are links?

Comment: yes they are links, means they can be clicked to go to a destination link clickin create content will open up a form for creating new content.

Answer (score 0):

If your real array is something like

```
array(
    [0]=> <a href="/">home</a>
    [1]=> <a href="/path/">groups</a>
    [2]=> <a href="/subpath/">my group</a>
    [3]=> <a href="/another/path/">Create content</a>
)
```

then you can try to use [preg-grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) so as to return all items that match your regExp pattern:

```
$content_links = preg_grep("/[YOUR REGEXP HERE]/", $breadcrumb);
// if you have matching items
if (0 < sizeof($content_links)) {
    // do some stuff - do `foreach` loop or use `array_diff`
}
```

**UPD**:
Or even you can use `PREG_GREP_INVERT` as third parameter and get all items that doens't match RegExp pattern.

Comment: array is like whta i hae described in the question, and clarified in the comments, thanks for chipping in..

Comment: If your array is like you described - then why are you using `strip_tags`?

Comment: this code does no work, specifically because using strip_tags make the anchored string a normal string, tht's all right but in the upper level`(in_array("Create content",$breadcrumb))` i don't know how to conert the anchored string..threfore the strip_tags is useless at the moment.

Comment: Once again - whats your array look like? Like in my answer or like in your question? If it's like in your question - it's useless to use `strip_tags` 'cause there're NO tags in your array values.

Comment: it looks like exactly what i have described in my question, yes I admit there's no use using strip_tags there. any ideas..?

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/7yi-ddk this code works with array you described in a question. If it doesnt't works with array you are working with - then I have some bad news for you. Your array has another structure or array values are different from what you described.